# Add footer to listview after setAdapter method has been called

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I want to add `footerview` to `listview` after setAdapter method has been called,

My process goes like following..

1. Get the data from Server using WCF service,
2. Create the `SimpleAdapter` using this data,
3. Check the status field of data, if it is `true` add footer to listview, if it is `false` should not add footer to listview,
4. set adapter to `ListView`

After some period of time

1. Get the data from Server using WCF service,
2. Check the status field of data, if it is `true`, How can I add footer to listview,
3. call `notifyDataSetChanged()` of adapter.

Here how can I add footer to `listview` before call `notifyDataSetChanged()` of adapter?

Any possible solution is very high voltage for me now..

Thanks,
Guna

Comment: Question: Why add a footer through getView when you can add one via ListView's `addFooterView()` method?

Comment: there is no mean to add fotter in getview may be use addFooterView() or doing some work with layout

Comment: Sorry, I have changed the question.. addFooterView method didnot worked after setadapter called..

Comment: It depends what version. Earlier versions don't allow it to be called after `setAdapter()`, iirc

Comment: @codeMagic In which version we can add footer after setAdapter..

Comment: Starting with 4.4 (KitKat) you can use it after `setAdapter`.

Comment: @user3249477 Is their any other possible way, I have to show one view as a footer of listview if status is true.

Comment: You can create a separate layout to use in `getView()` when the field is true. Or have it in the same layout and have its visibility as gone unless the field is true. Just check the position in getView() to only show it with the last position. Kind of hacky though. Or make it as a separate view below the listview